# How do I check if a Qname equals something when using StAX?

Tags: java, stax

I am trying to find all tags with the name accounts. I tried this...

```
logger.info("The tag is "+name+ " Is this an account? "+name.equalsIgnoreCase("account")+" "+ mapper.writeValueAsString(dmp.diffMain("account", name)));
```

But I get...

```
2021-03-22 08:38:20.738  INFO [,,,] 520 --- [           main] com.jgleason.AccountIT              : The tag is {http://refdata.me.com/2011}account Is this an account? false [{"operation":"INSERT","text":"{http://refdata.me.com/2011}"},{"operation":"EQUAL","text":"account"}]
```

Now I know I can parse out the `{}` but is there a cleaner way to just test the element name?

Answer (score 0):

Found it...

```
String name = end.getName().getLocalPart();
if(name.endsWith("account")){
    ...
}
```

Comment: What if it was `{http://refdata.me.com/2011}NotAnAccount`?

Comment: Sorry the ends with isn't really needed if you use localPart